# Make copy of DB2 database

Tags: copy, db2

How I can  make copy of DB2 database from one workstation and create new database based on this copy on another workstation (both Windows). I tried to make a backup of existing DB using Control Center  and creating new database in another workstation (from backup) but I no custom tables were imported.

EDIT:  I read about db2move coommand. But when i try use `db2move MY_DB_NAME import` command i get an error:

> application code page not determined using ansi codepage 1208

Comment: since you mentioned control center, I assume you are using DB2 version prior to 10.1?

Comment: @vaisakh , yes, my version is 9.7.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you have data in a single schema.

1. Create a new database:
   `db2 create database MyDstDb`
2. Copy schema:
   `db2move MySrcDb copy -sn MySrcSchema -co target_db MyDstDb -u MyDbUser -p`

I'm not sure if this works in 9.7. I currently use 10.1.

Comment: "-co target_db TARGET_DB" what does that mean?

Comment: `-co` means copy options, `target_db` means target database option and `TARGET_DB` means target database name. Maybe I should have used "my"... `db2move mysrcdb copy -sn mysrcschema -co target_db mytargetdb -u mydbuser -p`.

Comment: Yeah.. using "my_" could be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Added "My" now. Please, upvote the answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

DB2 provides various options to move data. Have a look at this page: [DB2 Data movement options](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/r0024482.html)

You will have to choose the best one according to your need here.